# Taskkill does not stop script

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code, but when I run it, the script does not stop.

```
taskkill -im "C:\Program Files\QLC\pme.bat"
```

How can I use `taskkill` to stop the batch script?

Comment: Open the task manager while pme.bat is running and it will be obvious why this doesn't work.

Comment: ... or run `tasklist`

Comment: how to insert <Enter> in below batch file
taskkill -im javaw.exe

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
taskkill /f /im "cmd.exe"
```

**EDIT**

Normally with the /f option of taskkill you'll not need to press the enter key.
So first try my first answer.

In case you really need to send the ENTER key :

```
@echo off&cls

if not exist enter.vbs (
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}") > enter.vbs

taskkill /f /im "javaw.exe"

cscript /nologo enter.vbs
```

Comment: Unless he has more than one instance of cmd.exe open. I'd recommend adding a title (with `title`) to the script that needs to be closed and using the `/FI "WINDOWTITLE eq <title>` option.

Comment: how to insert <Enter> in below batch file
taskkill -im javaw.exe

Comment: For what do you need to insert <Enter> ?

Comment: after running batch file taskkill -im javaw.exe, software ask yes or no, by default tab come on yes, so we need to enter to close the software,thats by iam asking how to put enter in command.